# Python дамп базы?

Tags: python, postgresql

По большому счету, вопроса у меня два. Но решают он общую задачу. Поэтому, простите, разделять их не буду.

Вот такой код:

```python
con = psycopg2.connect(user='*', password='*', host='*', dbname='*', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

today = date.today()
month = today.replace(year=today.year - 1, month=today.month, day=today.day)
month = month.strftime("%Y-%m")
cur.execute('''select * from "SC_Tag"."tagdata_%s";'''% month)

ver = cur.fetchone()
print ver

try:
    dumpcmd ='''PGPASSWORD="*" pg_dump -h *.ru -p 5432 -U * -F p -E UTF8 -Z 9 -t "SC_Tag"."tagdata_2014-12" -v -f "D:\postgres\pg\my12.gzip" DB_ASUTP_2'''    
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE "SC_Tag"."tagdata_%s";'''% month)
    print 'lol'
except:
    print "I can't drop our test database!"
print cur.query
```

Первое - не проходит удаление таблицы.

При этом он не ругается. Select проходит нормально. Права на удаление есть

Второе - не проходит dumpcmd.

Как вариант - нужно подключить файл с паролем. Но сейчас нет доступа к серверу, пишу на винде. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893954/how-to-pass-in-password-to-pg-dump) вроде говорят что и так его указать можно. Но опять же - ошибки вообще нет.

В чем проблема?

попробовал

```
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE "SC_Tag"."tagdata_%s";'''% month)
    cur.commit()

except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
    print 'Error %s' % e
```

получил

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/sql_python/load.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       cur.commit() AttributeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: попробуйте после удаления написать con.commit(). А вот на счет второго непонятно - что значит не проходит?

Comment: (64343431, 3, None, None, datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 18, 8, 20, 50), '3.96343565918505')
I can't drop our test database!
DROP TABLE "SC_Tag"."tagdata_2014-06";

Comment: при commit скатывается в ексепт

Comment: что за exception? напишите except Exception as e: print e

Comment: не cur.commit(), a con.commit()

Comment: Nexus можете свой комментарий в ответ писать. con.commit() решил проблему. а с дампом что за беда - и ошибки никакой нет. может я еще чего не указал?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24942/discussion-between-nexus-and-des1roer).

Comment: переходите в чат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы удаление прошло надо закоммитить сессию

```
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE "SC_Tag"."tagdata_%s";'''% month)
    print 'lol'
except:
    con.rollback()
    print "I can't drop our test database!"
con.commit()
print cur.query
```

Для того, чтобы заработал дамп базы добавте команду:

```
import os
....
r = os.popen(dumpcmd).read()
```

Не забудте заэкранировать слеши в *dumpcmd*.